# Dealing with a variable reported in two units of measurement

Tags: spss, units-of-measurement

I have two columns on SPSS, one is `Weight`, and the other is `Unit`. `Weight` is either reported on lbs or kgs, and the `Unit` is either 1 or 2 depending on the weight unit. How do I convert all the values into a single unit, say kgs so I can analyse it? Many thanks!

Comment: I would have thought that a line that "compute"-ed a new value , say all_kgs, initialized to Weight and then : IF  Unit=1 THEN Weight=Weight/2.2. Sorry that I cannot give tested code since the last time I wielded SPSS was in 1986.

Comment: @42, the principle is right, of course, but the code won't work... (guess spss syntax is not like riding a bike)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your units are 1=lbs, 2=kilos,

```
if units=2 kilos=weight.
if units=1 kilos=weight/2.20462 .
```

Or, of course

```
if units=2 lbs=weight*2.20462.
if units=1 lbs=weight .
```

And here's a way to do this in one line:

```
compute kilos=weight/(1+(2-unit)*1.20462).
```